# instantaneous velocity - reference previous value

Tags: r

Using a very simple equation, how can I calculate the instantaneous velocity.

```
Vi = V0 + acceleration * time
```

The following task is very easy with MS.Excel as one can click on the previous previous cell, but how do we call this in R?

```
acceleration <- c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1)
time <- rep(0.1,9)
df1 <- data.frame(acceleration, time)


df1$instant.vel <- df1$acceleration * df1$time + ....
```

Comment: Is there a column  for velocity in df1?

Comment: thats what we want to get

Comment: assuming v0 = 0, does cumsum(df1$acceleration * df1$time) give you what you want?

Comment: Would you please write the final values of Vi in this case to make sure of the required results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `dplyr::lag`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(V=(lag(acceleration,default=0)*lag(time,default=0))+(acceleration*time))

  acceleration time   V
1            1  0.1 0.1
2            2  0.1 0.3
3            3  0.1 0.5
4            4  0.1 0.7
5            5  0.1 0.9
6            4  0.1 0.9
7            3  0.1 0.7
8            2  0.1 0.5
9            1  0.1 0.3
```

Or step by step:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(V0=(acceleration*time)) %>% 
  mutate(V1=V0+(lag(acceleration,default=0)*lag(time,default=0)))
  acceleration time  V0  V1
1            1  0.1 0.1 0.1
2            2  0.1 0.2 0.3
3            3  0.1 0.3 0.5
4            4  0.1 0.4 0.7
5            5  0.1 0.5 0.9
6            4  0.1 0.4 0.9
7            3  0.1 0.3 0.7
8            2  0.1 0.2 0.5
9            1  0.1 0.1 0.3
```